# Strength of Magnet in Magnetic Bearings

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, magnetic-fields, electric-current

While reading about magnetic bearings, one reads about passive/active magnetic bearings. By passive, one means no electric current is put into the bearing for attaining magnetic levitation/flux. In the active case we mean, there is a solenoid that provides for the magnetic levitation/flux to achieve separation, and almost frictionless operations. The question is what is the strength of magnetic fields in both cases in typical applications of these bearings. For instance, the bearings are able to handle a load of about 200lbs, and has three poles. What is the field strength in the passive case, and active case for such a load bearing, even if there is a different load specification, one can indicate the field strengths used in such bearings.